# How to generate a RowPointer that works with Infor's Syteline software's SQL database

Tags: sql

We currently use Infor Syteline to manage our manufacturing and customer information. I am working on an alternative front end (vb.net) software that would work seamlessly with our Syteline software to add custom document generation and other functions to a SQL database and the only problem I am running into is with generating RowPointers that Syteline uses. Example of one of these pointers is below:

F5025224-046D-40DC-95F6-C517303A0D26

Can someone fill me in on what these pointers do, how I can replicate them, and why standard ID's aren't used to reference rows? The goal is to be able to add entries into the SQL database that are identical to those created by Syteline so that both softwares can be used to manage customer data, production data, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Is Syteline a dbms? Or is it using a  dbms - which one?

Comment: AFAIK syteline is a paid product, and the source code is not openly available. You should really contact support.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate them with `select newid()`. They are always unique, so you can use them to filter on 1 specific row. They will never have a duplicate.

Not sure what you mean by standard ID.